# System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1: 'Session was closed. Please, login again' (C# web service)

Tags: c#, web-services, console-application

I've created a web service, and even though it connects and extracts data from a response method, it gets hung up on this error:

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1: 'Session was closed. Please, login again'

[image]

When I run a step-into the debugging it's this part of the code which sets it off:

```
public object BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel)
    {
        //Get the HttpRequestMessage property from the message
        HttpRequestMessageProperty httpreq = null;

        try
        {
            httpreq = request.Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] as HttpRequestMessageProperty;
        }
        catch //(Exception exc)
        {
        }

        if (httpreq == null)
        {
            httpreq = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
            request.Properties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, httpreq);
        }

        byte[] authbytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Concat(Username, ":", Password));
        string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(authbytes);
        string authorization = string.Concat("Basic ", base64);

        httpreq.Headers["Authorization"] = authorization;

        return null;
    }
```

Does anyone know how to kill a session in a C# console app to make sure this doesn't continue to happen?

Thanks!

Comment: I was going to drop the image as it didn't add anything to the question, then I noticed that the partially obscured code in the image doesn't appear in the code in your question. Can you clarify where you get the error?

Comment: It's in the code I pasted above. Essentially it jumps after the return null; to the catch. There really isn't an "error" per se as I've gotten this service to work, I just don't understand this behavior and seeing if someone can lend me a hand in better understanding and/or fixing this problem.

Comment: This question helped me for something completely unrelated. I also had a situation where I needed to set "view settings" first before calling the endpoint I was attempting. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind the question. This issue was coming about because my code is dependent on another web session to establish a connection first. This is why I'm getting the "session was closed" error, because I'm running the project without opening up the other service.

Thank you.